# How to draw a shape on an existing video on HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am trying to make a website that allow me to draw any kind of shape on an existing video.
I tried to put my code that draws any shape on top of the video but it disappears once I run the code.
Can someone please show me how to do that or what to use.
I am using HTML5, jquery, javascript to make this website.

Here is where and how am calling the video and the javascript file

## Injury Scope

```
<div id="container">  
    <canvas id="imageView" width="755" height="430"></canvas>   
</div>  

<video id="sampleMovie" src="around.mp4" controls>  

</video>  

    <script src="example1.js">  

    </script>
```

The code for the drawing works just fine

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: Yes I can, I just want to know if it is possible to draw a line or a shape on a video and how or using what plugin or anything. I looked online but I can't seem to find a good answer

Comment: Your question is not so well formatted. You could be more humble in the comments. You should ask more explicitly what you want *("it's possible? where should I look for?")*. If the code works, you are asking for a tool to do the job, or someone to do it for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply create a `div` and put a `video` element in that just like this:

```
<div>
    <video src="http://v2v.cc/~j/theora_testsuite/320x240.ogg" loop autoplay>Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.</video>
</div>
```

For this example i have made the `div` fit the screen, and gave the video a `height` and `width`of `auto` and the `min-height` and `min-width` to `100%`. I have done this with the following code:

```
div {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}
video {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

When i want to draw a shape on the video, i use the `:before` code on the `div` like this:

```
div:before {
    position: absolute;
    content:"";
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: purple;
}
```

Now you can customize that to your needs.

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/aRRku/2/)**

Comment: @MichelAyres sorry if I have offended you or offended anyone but I didn't see it the way you did. My appologies

Comment: @user2302278 No problem :) but can you accept my answer so other people can see this issue is fixed?

Comment: @user2302278 You didn't offend me at all :) If it's about the comment on your question, I explained **why** I DV, so you could fix it and I could redraw my DV. there are other 4 that DV it and didn't post a comment. If it's about the link demo comment in the +Dreiba's answer, I do not understand why would I get offended ... StackExchange network (StackOverflow in this case), has a policy of post question and answers that MAY help others that seek for a similar problem. When you post a question, try to post one question that YOU would answer. So, try to put some explanation and examples.

Comment: @user2302278 Saying "Yes I can post my code that would help me and others to find a good/exelent answer, but I won't because I just want some code to solve my problem and I don't care about the rest" is not a way to go. This is why I said "Be more humbled" :) hope to see you again with great questions and answer around xD